# MAAS ipmi issues on blade server HS21 XM

Tags: maas, ipmi

I am not able to power on/off all the node from an IBM blade server HS21 XM. Everytime a blade boots from network, maas assign to its BMC card an ip 192.199.199.8x that I think is not available in my network. When MAAS try to connect through IPMI I get the error

> Connection timed out while performing power action. Check BMC configuration and connectivity and try again.

This is the screenshot from MAAS:

[image: MAAS]

This is the BMC setting:

[image: BMC setting in BIOS]

How can I manage through MAAS these blades? Maybe the problem is in the configurated IP for the BMC. How can I change permanently this IP?
Obviously, if I choose manual power type I am able to get a node "Ready", but this is not what I want. Could you please help me?

Comment: Maybe I can use a fence_bladecenter command from MAAS but I am unable to let it work, there is no custom power type.

Comment: Is your IPMI on the same VLAN as MAAS? It's important that you have your subnetand vlan configured so that your MAAS server can both talk to the IPMI and your servers. You should install fing, nmap, etc on your master node and do a discovery on the subnet 192.199.199.0/24. If your IPMI appears (ending in bb:a4) then you are fine. If you don't see it, then neither can MAAS, which explains your error.

Comment: They are on a different vlan and subnet, but these details are set directly by MAAS. On the MAAS server I get nmap -Pn 192.199.199.82

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-12-12 15:56 CET
Nmap scan report for 192.199.199.82
Host is up.
All 1000 scanned ports on 192.199.199.82 are filtered

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 201.68 seconds

Comment: If the IPMI is on a different vlan, you need to configure your MAAS node to have an interface to the IPMI and to the server NICs.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have enable Serial over LAN on IPMI configuration ?

MAAS Server need SoL access to communicates with IPMI.

Thanks,

Comment: Yes it is enabled